# Работа с числовыми значениями в строке

Tags: java, android

К примеру имеется строка - " Купил 10 бананов потратил 5 рублей".
 Строка может изменять количество слов, само число, но количество цифровых значений всегда одинакова.

Как внести по отдельности все цифровые значения из строки в массив?

Подскажите как решить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поиск групп цифр в строке и их добавление в список:

```
String str = "abc 10 def ghi 5 jkl";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find())
{
    matches.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Захватывать группу не обязательно. Можно просто матчить на "\\d+" и тогда `group(0)` даст тот же результат.

Comment: @Agrgg тогда уж можно и `group()` написать вместо `group(0)` - сэкономить один символ. Да, в данном случае `group(0)` даст тот же результат, что и `group(1)`, однако использование `group(0)` для захвата первой группы рано или поздно может выйти боком.

Comment: Ребят, возникла проблемка - если число не целое , например 3.14 то регулярка разбивает его на 3 и 14  , как быть?

Comment: @evb если нужно просто положительное дробное число через точку, то подойдёт такое регулярное выражение: `(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)`. Оно подойдёт и для целых, и для дробных, так что спокойно можно заменить представленное в ответе выражение на это. Если нужно для более сложных случаев (знак, степень и т.д.), то об этом стоит спрашивать отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @Regent Не скажите, группы в регулярных выражениях влияют не только на количество символов, но и на производительность. Конечно, в таком простом случае влияние ничтожно мало, но в качестве общего правила не стоит злоупотреблять группами.

Answer (score 2):

Я далек от Java, но разве нельзя итерировать строку и проверять, не является ли [символ числовым](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)? Если является — в массив (или в более подходящую для задачи структуру)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться регулярными выражениями. Объявить шаблон, который ищет числовые группы, применить его ко входной строке и потом пройти по всем группам. Примерно так:

```
String line = "Купил 10 бананов потратил 5 рублей";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

while (matcher.find()) {
    //Здесь matcher.group(0) -- это будет найденное число в строковом виде
    System.out.println("Found: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

Код выше должен вывести:

```
Found: 10
Found: 5
```

Подробнее о регулярных выражениях написано [здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm), похожий вопрос, только со словами вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884484/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-android)